# Wordpress User Gravatar images not displaying. Loading default instead

Tags: avatar, gravatar

I'm trying to display user [gravatars](http://en.gravatar.com/) on this page http://gepc.themelot.com/survey-comparison/433747624/293281083/ but the page keeps showing the default '[mystery man](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/#default-image)' avatar. I inspected the page element and it returns the same URL with the same hash value for the gravatar link.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if (!empty($matched_answers)) { ?>
    <h1><?php $user = get_user_by( 'user_login', $matched_answers[0]['user'] ); echo get_avatar( $user->ID , 256 ).' '.$matched_answers[0]['user'].' - '.round($matched_answers[0]['percentage'], 2).' &#37;'; ?></h1>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Percentage</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($matched_answers as $value) {
                $user = get_user_by( 'user_login', $value['user'] );
                $user_email = $user->user_email;
                $url = 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5( $user_email );
                $url = add_query_arg( array(
                's' => 48,
                'd' => 'mm',
                ), $url );
                $gravatar_url = esc_url_raw( $url );
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.'<img src='.$gravatar_url.' />'.'<td>';
                echo '<td>'.$value['user'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="votepercent">' . round($value['percentage'], 2) . ' &#37;</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
<?php }
?>
```

How do I return the user's actual gravatar image? What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my specific case. I ended up using `get_user_by('login', $value)` Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    foreach ($matched_answers as $value) {
    $user           = get_user_by('login', $value['user']);
    $gravatar_url = get_avatar( $user->user_email, 60);        
    echo '<tr style="margin-bottom:10px;">';
    echo '<td width="33.33333%">' . $gravatar_url . '</td>';
    echo '<td width="33.33333%" class="votepercent">' . round($value['percentage'], 2) . ' &#37; of issues</td>';
    echo '<td width="33.33333%" class="tbtn"><a class="btn btn-primary">View Responses</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all your images on that page have issues. For example: http://gravatar.com/avatar/619d8e38359241a952a1f9b67f1f36cd?s=60&d=mm

The rest of the images aren't displaying because the emails you've encoded are not recognized with [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/). The default image shows because you are specifying to use `mm` when the image can't be found for your hash. They have several tips for normalizing the email like `trim` and `strtolower` to get a better hash hit.

### [Creating a hash](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/):

1. Trim leading and trailing whitespace from an email address
2. Force all characters to lower-case
3. md5 hash the final string

> echo md5( strtolower( trim( "MyEmailAddress@example.com " ) ) );

```
  $user = get_user_by( 'user_login', $value['user'] );
  $user_email = $user->user_email;

  $url = 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5(strtolower(trim($user_email)));
  $url = add_query_arg( array(
    's' => 80,
    'd' => 'mm',
  ), $url );

  $gravatar_url = esc_url_raw( $url );
```

### [Gravatar API](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) - [Default Image](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/#default-image)

Change the default image from `mm` to `https%3A%2F%2Fplacekitten.com%2F256%2F256` by specifying the `d` parameter.

http://gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=250&d=https%3A%2F%2Fplacekitten.com%2F256%2F256

404: do not load any image if none is associated with the email hash, instead return an HTTP 404 (File Not Found) response

- **mm**: (mystery-man) a simple, cartoon-style silhouetted outline of a person (does not vary by email hash)
- **identicon**: a geometric pattern based on an email hash
- **monsterid**: a generated 'monster' with different colors, faces, etc
- **wavatar**: generated faces with differing features and backgrounds
- **retro**: awesome generated, 8-bit arcade-style pixelated faces
- **blank**: a transparent PNG image (border added to HTML below for demonstration purposes)

---

> Just remember, not every email has a gravatar which is why the default image exists.

Comment: I edited the code with yours but I still get the same image. The same URL is repeated. Please see the implementation in the question.

Comment: Updated with more info from the API

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks more or less OK. Have you considered that these users simply don't have a Gravatar associated with their email?

Generally speaking, one should use built-in WordPress functions whenever possible to reduce risk of errors and making the code more future proof. For Gravatar, there is [`get_avatar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/). For your use case, it would look like this:

```
$user_id = 0;
$user = get_user_by( 'user_login', $value['user'] );
if ( $user ) {
  $user_id = $user->ID;
}
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . get_avatar( $user_id, 48, 'mm' ) .'<td>';
```

As you can see, you can pass the user ID (or an email address) to the function, specify the size and the default avatar. The function returns the complete `<img>` tag with the avatar, making the code much more readable.

If there's still no individual Gravatar being displayed, the users really do not have a Gravatar. Simple as that.